# Eclipse generates Javadoc tags with 'ı' instead of 'i'

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I am triying to create a javadoc for this simple class. Source code of the class is here:

```
package com.xxproj;
/**
 * Bu sınıf bir aracı temsil etmektedir.
 * @author Bahadır Yılmaz
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public class Car {
    private String make;
    private int year;
    private int mileage;
    /**
     * Car sınıfının temel tanımlamalarını yapar.
     * @param make Aracın üretici firması
     * @param year Aracın üretim yılı
     * @param mileage Aracın yaptığı mesafe
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public Car(String make, int year, int mileage) {
        this.make = make;
        this.year = year;
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }
    /**
     * Aracı hareket ettirir.
     * @param miles Aracın hareket edeceği mesafe
     * @since 1.0.0  
     */
    public void drive(int miles) {
        if(miles > 0)
            mileage += miles;
    }
    /**
     * Aracın yaptığı toplam mesafe bilgisini verir.
     * @return milage Aracın yaptığı toplam mesafe
     */
    public int getMileage() {
        return mileage;
    }
    /**
     * Aracın üretici firma bilgisini verir.
     * @return make Aracın üretici firması
     */
    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }
    /**
     * Aracın üretim yılı bilgisini verir.
     * @return year Aracın üretim yılı
     */
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

}
```

I follow this article to create javadoc :

[Article about creating javadocs](http://learnjava-soa.blogspot.in/2015/06/how-to-generate-java-document-in-eclipse.html)

But at the end when i check the index.html, i see that all of **'i'** characters in html tags seen as **'ı'** (dotless i). So html page cannot be shown correctly.

[image]

I try same processes with jdk 1.7.0_79 and 1.7.0_80 and both of 32 bit and 64 bit versions. Also i try to change eclipse text file encoding from Windows->Pref->General->Workspace but nothing change.

Where I could be wrong? Thans for your opinions.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the html page with a web browser?

Comment: YES, HERE IS RESULT(ONLY HTML CONTENT SEEN):

Generated Documentation (Untitled) targetPage = "" + window.location.search; if (targetPage != "" && targetPage != "undefined") targetPage = targetPage.substring(1); if (targetPage.indexOf(":") != -1 || (targetPage != "" && !validURL(targetPage))) targetPage = "undefined"; function validURL(url) { try { url = d...

Comment: But when i change all 'ı' characters with 'i', there is no problem. But why eclipse creates tags with 'ı' character, i don't understand.

Comment: Since the language code is Turkish something might be running in to the issue where lower casing an I gives dotless-i in Turkish instead of dotted-i